# for searching between specific lines in a file with only FIND command in linux command

Tags: linux, find, command, line

i want to use only FIND command in linux and search between specific lines in a file for example find a word "hello" between lines 2 and 4 of a file named test.txt,please help.

Comment: `find` doesn't look inside files, it looks in directories. What you're asking doesn't make sense.

Comment: u know i searched alot and didn't find anything,thank u for ur response cause this was a question that my stupid teacher asked,by the way i think he doesn't know anything.i dont know what did he wanted to ask?

Comment: @Mat do u know how can we do this with GREP?

Comment: Use google: `extract lines between site:stackoverflow.com`

Comment: Provide sample input and output.

Answer (score 0):

By this way you can use `grep` command but not using `find` for sure.

```
grep -w "hello" test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The following example uses `find` to display all .txt files containing the word "hello":

```
find -name '*.txt' -exec grep -q hello \{\} \; -a -exec echo \{\} \;
```

You might be able to modify the `grep` expression to only match where the targeted word is between certain lines.

If your teacher is asking you not to find files which have this match but is instead asking you to match within a specific known file then they have misinformed you - `find` is most certainly *not* the command for that job, making your question unanswerable.